# how to create a custom login page in salesforce.com?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

is it possible to create a custom login page in salesforce.com? if so can anyone provide help to create the page and the validations part?

Answer (score 7):

A couple of things to think about:

- Is this page going to be hosted on your website?
- Is this going to be used for multiple salesforce organizations?

One thing you can do is use the [login()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_login.htm#topic-title) API call to get a session id.  You will be able to tell if the login fails, and alert the user appropriately.

From there, you will have to redirect the user through the "frontdoor.jsp" page which has the following format:

- https://**[host]**.salesforce.com/secur/frontdoor.jsp?sid=**[session_id]**&retURL=**[start_page]**

Where:

- **[host]** - varies by organization.  Some that I've seen are na1, na2, ....  If you are only building this for 1 organization, you could hard-code this value.  If you are building the for multiple organizations, you could parse it from the serverUrl property of the returned [LoginResult](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_login_loginresult.htm#topic-title).
- **[session_id]** - get this from the returned [LoginResult](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_login_loginresult.htm#topic-title)
- **[start_page]** - this is optional but can be used to "deep link" a user to a page after they've logged in.

**Edit: 2014-08-25**

Salesforce now officially supports the frontdoor.jsp method of login described in this answer ([link](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000193348&language=en_US)).  In addition, session_ID tokens can be obtained from any of the following sources:

1. The access_token from an OAuth authentication.Note that one of the scopes specified when you create a Connected App must be web or full.
2. The LoginResult returned from a SOAP API login() call
3. The Apex UserInfo.getSessionId()

Comment: Do you know if there is a way this can be done without having to use the security token?

Comment: If you go to: Setup -> Security Controls -> Network Access, you can add IP address ranges to your trusted network.  If this is not known or changes, you have to use a security token.  On a side note, there appears to be another way to do this using OAuth (http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com).  If you set `scope` to `id api refresh_token web`, you can generate generate session ids that you can pass to `frontdoor.jsp` for authentication.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - the link has no information on it though. :( But I am going to investigate this further thank you!

Comment: Ugg, try this: http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com

Answer (score 3):

This is possible using the Ajax Toolkit, I wrote up how and shared the code http://brianpeddle.com/2011/06/06/building-a-custom-salesforce-login/

I know this is old but if someone stumbles across this it may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There's some information [here](http://sites.force.com/ideaexchange/apex/ideaview?id=08730000000BqQmAAK), on the Salesforce ideas site.  Salesforce.com does not currently support a custom login page, however it sounds like you maybe be able to accomplish this using [Force.com sites](http://developer.force.com/sites).

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for your response and i have bit confused.
I thought salesforce.com is developing point for force.com. Is there any difference between them. Can you explain please